# prove that the unique language $A$ such that $AB$ is context free for all languages B is the empty set

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

> Prove that the unique language $A\subseteq \Sigma^*$ such that $AB$ is context free for all languages $\subseteq \Sigma^*$ is the empty set.

If $A$ is not the empty set, there should be a way to construct a language $B$ so that $AB$ is not context-free. I'm not sure how to generalize this for arbitrary nonempty languages $A$ however. The language $\{0^n 1^n 0^n : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is known to be non-context-free. Also, removing finitely many strings from a non-context-free language results in a non-context free language.

> Edit: perhaps modifying the language given will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $AB$ is context-free, so should be the set of all its suffixes. Those include the suffixes of $B$, and if $B$ is complicated enough prefixing $A$ does not change the complexity of the set of suffixes.

Your solution $B = \{0^n1^n0^n \mid \dots \}$ seems to work, but if $A$ ends in $0^*$ the reasoning becomes a little complicated. I would suggest $B' = \{10^n1^n0^n \mid \dots \}$.